# Can you check my proof? 9x9 square array with 81 numbers, to prove that product of $k^{th}$ row and column not equal.

Tags: matrices

The problem goes like this: "The numbers from 1 to 81 are written in a 9 X 9 square array.
Prove that there exists a positive integer k such that the product of the numbers in row
k does not equal the product of the numbers in column k."

I tried to prove this by contradiction. Assume there is no such k, then observe that both in the product of the elements of columns and rows there will be the common element a[k,k] with all the rest of the elements different, so the two products cannot be equal, so the assumption was false and there exists such a k.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: there are 10 primes from 41 to 79  inclusive. All are larger than $\frac{81}{2}.$ At the same time, the main diagonal has space for nine numbers only.

Comment: meanwhile, it is easy to get repeated products, $6 \cdot 10 \cdot 15 = 4 \cdot 9 \cdot 25$   for example

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let us write the $9\times 9$-matrix as $A$.

1. Let $p$ be any prime in $\{41,42,\ldots, 81\}$ such that $p$ is NOT on the diagonal of $A$, **if there is any such $p$** [we will show later that there indeed always must be such a prime $p$]. Let $k$ be the integer in $\{1,2,\ldots, 9\}$ such that $p$ is in row $k$ of the matrix $A$.
2. Thus, as $p$ is not in the diagonal of $A$, then $p$ is not in column $k$ of $A$.
3. In addition, as $p$ is at least $41$, there is no other multiple of $p$ in $\{1,2, \ldots, 81\}$ besides $p$ itself.
4. Thus, as $p$ is in row $k$ of $A$, the product of the entries in row $k$ of $A$ are divisible by $p$. However, as $p$ is not in column $k$ of $A$ and there are no other multiples of $p$ in $\{1,2,\ldots, 81\}$, the product of the entries in column $k$ of $A$ are not divisible by $p$.
5. So the product of the entries in row $k$ of $A$, is distinct from the product of the entries in column $k$ of $A$, as the former is divisble by $p$ and the latter not.
6. **So the moral of the story is this:** if there exists a prime $p \in \{41,42,\ldots, 81\}$ such that $p$ is NOT on the diagonal of the $9 \times 9$-matrix $A$, then there exists a $k \in \{1,2,\ldots, 9\}$ such that the product of the entries in row $k$ of $A$, is distinct from the product of the entries in column $k$ of $A$.
7. Thus it remains to show that, no matter how the numbers $1,2,\ldots, 81$ are written in $A$, there must always exists a prime $p \in \{41,42,\ldots, 81\}$ that ends up not on the diagonal of $A$. We do this next.

You can check that there are $10$ primes $p \in \{41,42,\ldots, 81\}$, but there are only $9$ integers in $\{1,2,\ldots, 81\}$ that get to be a diagonal element of $A$. Can you finish from here. Indeed, can you conclude that there always must be at least $10-9=1$ prime $p \in \{41,42,\ldots, 81\}$ that are not on the diagonal of $A$.

Comment: "You can check that there are 10
 primes p∈{41,42,…,81}
, but there are only 9
 integers in {1,2,…,81}
 that get to be a diagonal element of A
. Can you finish from here." I think this follows from the pigeonhole principle. Although I don't see yet why there must be at least 2 primes p∈{41,42,…,81}
  that are not on the diagonal of A.

Comment: Also, thank you for the great answer!